# Magin-top не работает

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.prog
{
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.2);
}

.servbar
{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.prog_bg
{
    margin:20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset,0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1) inset,0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="servbar">
<div class="prog_bg"><div class="prog"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде работает.

```css
.prog
{
 margin-top: 100px;
 background-color: rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.2);
}

.servbar
{

  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.prog_bg
{
    margin:20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3) inset,0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1) inset,0 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="servbar">
<div class="prog_bg"><div class="prog"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скриншот посмотри

Comment: а как это должно работать по вашему? есть такой скриншот?